# formatting window 10 dual boot with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot

i have dual boot system window 10 and ubuntu 18.04. My window corrupted and now it is not opening, Is there any possibilities to repair window from ubuntu or boot.
And also let me know how can i format window 10 from ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

- If the corruption is because any file missing you can mount the windows partions through `Nautilus` file Manager in Ubuntu.
- You can access the NTFS, FAT and many Other partions in Ubuntu.
- If the Partions are Not listed in Nautilus Open `Disks`.

  1. Choose Your HDD from Left Side Box.
  2. Click on your Volume
  3. Click on Play ICON which will mount the Partition
  4. Now the volume Will Appear On your File manager.
  5. Do what you have to do to solve the issue.

### Removing Windows

For Removing Windows Format the Windows System Partition
and run the below Command on your Terminal (To Open`Ctl`+`Alt`+`t`)

> sudo update-grub